# Открытие файлов .pdf и .zip из ресурсов

Tags: javascript, java, html, android

Как открыть файл *.pdf* из ресурсов?

При запуске приложения отображается HTML страница. В ней есть ссылки на разные документы *.zip* и *.pdf*, но они не открываются. В уведомлении пишет, что файл не существует или его невозможно открыть.

```
<img height="18" width="18" alt="" src="file:///android_asset/images/pdf.png" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<a href="file:///android_asset/manuals/skat1200.pdf" title="http://bast.ru/media/bastion/manuals/skat1200.pdf">Паспорт на прибор</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

У Вас ссылки ведут на файловую систему пользователя, а не на сервер. Например, в

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/manuals/skat1200.pdf" title="http://bast.ru/media/bastion/manuals/skat1200.pdf">Паспорт на прибор</a>
```

достаточно перенести значение из title в href, и файл откроется.